# How can I adjust the width of the column of html table?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot solve the following problem which is shown in the snapshot. I have tried to reduce the width of the column but there is no effect and I really cannot solve the problem?

[image]
This is code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive" id="table1">
                 <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Sl_no:</th>
                        <th>KPI</th>
                        <th style='width:10px'>Weight(RGoB)</th>
                        <th>Target Achieved(RGoB)</th>
                        <th>Points Scored(RGoB)</th>
                        <th>Weight(External)</th>
                        <th>Target Achieved(External)</th>
                        <th>Points Scored(External)</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <?php $id=1;
                  $proposed_kpi=App\Tbl_proposed_KPI::where('activity_id',$approved_activity->activity_id)->get();
                  foreach($proposed_kpi as $kpi):
                  ?>
                  <?php 
                    $approved_kpi=App\Tbl_KPI_approved::where('kpi_id',$kpi->kpi_id)->get();
                    foreach($approved_kpi as $approved):
                 ?>

                  <tr>
                    <td>{{$id++}}</td>
                    <td>{{$approved->approved_kpi_name}}</td>
                    <td class='td1'>{{$approved->approved_RGoB}}</td>
                    <td class='td2'><input type="text" name="target[]" id="target" style='width:100px' required></td>
                    <td class='td3'><input type="text" name="rgob_score[]" id="rgob_score" style='width:100px;border:none;' placeholder="double click"></td>
                    <td class='external'>{{$approved->approved_external}}</td>
                    <td class='td5'><input type="text" name="target1[]" id="target" style='width:100px' required></td>
                    <td class='td4'><input type="text" name="external_score[]" id="external_score" style='width:100px;border:none;' placeholder="double click"></td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value='{{$approved->kpi_approval_id}}'>
                  </tr>

                <?php endforeach ?>
              <?php endforeach ?>
              </tbody>
              </table>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Could you show us css for table elements also?!

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Fix the container above this table. Are you using Bootstrap or any other framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using laravel framework and bootstrap too. I tried to include datatable

Comment: I don't have the css for this table. I am using it in laravel with bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1):

Set width to 100% and table-layout must be fixed in style.

You can do something like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%; display: table; table-layout: fixed;" class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center table-hover table-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `div` around your `table` and to put the `table-responsive` class on it, and not on the table itself

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table ...>
     ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but still i couldn't solve the problem.